# How to batch import OGRE .mesh'es with flipped coordinates to blender scene?

Tags: python

so let say that I have textual file with XYZ coordinate's, rotation angle, name of object without extension (.mesh) so I need to add extension at end of the name of importing mesh in blender script, here is example

```
// x        y        z    rx  ry rz odefname
875.549, 67.6607, 1155.26, 0, 0, 0, truckshop

2193.36, 63.4740, 4053.33, 0.0,  75.00, 0, Parkinglight1-1
2200.58, 63.4842, 4058.88, 0.0,  30.00, 0, Parkinglight1-1
2204.91, 63.5865, 4066.00, 0.0,  30.00, 0, Parkinglight1-1
2208.67, 63.5398, 4073.17, 0.0,  30.00, 0, Parkinglight1-1
2212.95, 63.4549, 4080.69, 0.0,  30.00, 0, Parkinglight1-1
2216.85, 63.3441, 4088.01, 0.0,  30.00, 0, Parkinglight1-1
2221.18, 63.3960, 4095.91, 0.0,  30.00, 0, Parkinglight1-1

2078.567,   64.027, 2981.528,   90.0,    0.0,  150.6, Gas_station_sign1
2028.042,   63.952, 2983.989,   90.0,    0.0,  330.6, Caseys-store
2056.075,   63.884, 2980.586,   90.0,    0.0,  150.6, Caseys-pumpisland
2024.180,   63.888, 3020.363,   90.0,    0.0,  330.6, Gas_station1
```

and I want to import all of them to blender but with flipped coordinates
+Y is front, +X is right and +Z is up. So how could do this in blender3 ?

EDIT:
So I tried ChatGPT but Im getting an error

```
import bpy
import math

coordinate_file = "/PathToFile/object.tobj"

with open(coordinate_file, "r") as file:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(file, start=1):
        parts = line.strip().split(",")

    # Check if the line has enough elements
    if len(parts) < 7:
        print(f"Error: Insufficient values in line {line_num}: {line}")
        continue

    try:
        coordinates = [float(coord) for coord in parts[:3]]  # Extract position coordinates
        rotations = [float(rot) for rot in parts[3:6]]  # Extract rotation values
        object_name = parts[6].strip()  # Extract the object name

        # Import the .mesh.xml file
        bpy.ops.wm.ogre_xml_import(filepath=f"/PathToFile/{object_name}.mesh.xml")

        # Get the imported mesh object
        mesh_object = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]

        # Set the object's location based on the coordinates
        mesh_object.location = coordinates

        # Convert rotation values to radians
        rotations = [math.radians(rot) for rot in rotations]

        # Set the object's rotation based on the rotation values
        mesh_object.rotation_euler = rotations

    except ValueError:
        print(f"Error: Unable to convert values to float in line {line_num}: {line}")
```

and error is

```
AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.wm.ogre_xml_import" error, could not be found
```

Comment: Hello, AFAIK there is no builtin xml importer to Blender, but if it does follow an xml schema you can try with https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html to parse the file